# How to develop a simple database

Tags: python, mysql, database

I have some knowledge of programming, and I am quite happy with procedural programming in Python and C, that I mainly use for mathematical problems. I've learnt some OOP too.
I've been asked from a friend to develop a simple software to be used by medical attendants.
Basically they should be able to access a list of patients and add, remove or edit them.
They could also click on the name of a patient and access a page with date of birth and the details of that patient. Moreover, each patient should have a "history" of medical examinations, with dates and details of whatever he's done in the past. That's just to give you the general picture of the situation.

Now, I know how to work with GUI in Python (Tkinter libraries). I was wondering whether there is a way of using the sole python, but I guess I need to use some DB too, perhaps MySQL.

Am I correct?
What would you suggest to develop such a simple piece of software?

Thank you.

Comment: sqlite3 comes builting with python

Comment: While you may not need a full blown relational database, the basic design principles will be extremely helpful for you. Give this a read to get started http://www.deeptraining.com/litwin/dbdesign/FundamentalsOfRelationalDatabaseDesign.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Simple interface does not always imply simple software (just a friendly word of caution).

Your program will end up being event-driven (e.g. "do this when this button is clicked") as opposed to procedural, so you will definitely be on a learning curve in that respect. You will be forced to learn new ways of handling your data (procedural code can just pass data forwards, while event-driven software will often need to access things in more or less random order). This is where database software can help. It separates your data from your code.

Using a database such as MySQL is quite nice, especially compared to creating your own database, which would be reinventing the wheel in this case. Most database software will handle what you're looking to do quite well (and several are free, including MySQL).

I'd suggest starting off with some simple "get to know MySQL" programs to get used to querying, inserting, etc. There are several excellent tutorials online ([W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com) has one).

When learning how to use a database effectively it pays to really plan out everything you'd like it to store, e.g. name, birthday, address, phone#. You'll likely have to reconstruct your database table(s) a few times while you learn what works and what doesn't.

If you're not on a deadline this is an excellent learning opportunity!

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with [phpacademy.org](https://phpacademy.org/courses)?  They have a number of excellent tutorials that would meet your needs.

Here are a few that might help:

[MySQL and PHP](https://phpacademy.org/course/mysql-and-php)
[PHP Security](https://phpacademy.org/course/php-security)
[Register & Login](https://phpacademy.org/course/register-login)

Note that all tutorials/videos are free if watched on YouTube. Alex only charges for the code (a timesaver if you don't want to type it all in yourself while watching the examples) and he accepts donations.

I learned most of my stuff from this guy. Owe him a lot, donated a little.

Comment: It's a Python question. Why are you giving links to PHP tutorials?

Comment: https://phpacademy.org/courses?search=python gives no tutorials related with python. Sorry but you missleading the OP goal.

Comment: Hey guys, read the question. The OP said he is proficient with python and would be happy to use it. However, he specifically asks: "Am I correct? What would you suggest to develop such a simple piece of software?" OP has left the question open for other approaches. I suspect he just wants to solve the problem, not solve it in any specific way. Rather than self-righteously downvoting, how about you pony up some ideas of your own?

Comment: Since PHP & MySQL are very often coupled together (e.g. LAMP), and MySQL syntax is the same regardless of the language used to connect to the database, I'd say that the links @gibberish provided are pretty relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Start with this simple example

**Inserting data**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sqlite3 as lite
import sys

con = lite.connect('test.db')

with con:

    cur = con.cursor()    
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Cars(Id INT, Name TEXT, Price INT)")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(1,'Audi',52642)")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(2,'Mercedes',57127)")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(3,'Skoda',9000)")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(4,'Volvo',29000)")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(5,'Bentley',350000)")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(6,'Citroen',21000)")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(7,'Hummer',41400)")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(8,'Volkswagen',21600)")
```

**Retrieving data**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sqlite3 as lite
import sys


con = lite.connect('test.db')

with con:    

    cur = con.cursor()    
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Cars")

    rows = cur.fetchall()

    for row in rows:
        print row
```

**Print the data to the console, row by row.**

```
$ ./retrieveall.py
(1, u'Audi', 52642)
(2, u'Mercedes', 57127)
(3, u'Skoda', 9000)
(4, u'Volvo', 29000)
(5, u'Bentley', 350000)
(6, u'Citroen', 21000)
(7, u'Hummer', 41400)
(8, u'Volkswagen', 21600)
```

Source: http://zetcode.com/db/sqlitepythontutorial/

Answer (score 0):

First of all, do you really need to create a GUI for this ? Or does a web page suit your needs?
If a website is ok for you, I suggest you to have a look at [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/), or [django](https://www.djangoproject.com/). (The second one will take longer to learn).

If you are using these technologies, you can use [flask-sqlalchemy](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/) in order to play with the database for flask, or the [django-orm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/). I still suggest that you should learn a bit about SQL (which is the 'database language'), but with these libraries you won't need to write your own SQL queries.

You can find good tutorials about these frameworks, and a lot of people to help you if you're stuck.